# php notifications causing massive load

Tags: php, apache, drupal-6

We have 3 drupal webservers (pressflow 6.22) behind a load balancer. Due to a update we are getting a ton of notices from php, while we try to fix these I simply wanted to disable the notices. So I changed the PHP.ini from

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
```

to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

As soon as I did this, load on the machines skyrocketed by 30x, the number of DB connections doubled.

As soon as I set it back everything went back to normal.

I don't understand how suppressing the notices could cause so much grief. Is it simply putting to much overhead on php to filter those out or something?

A lot of these errors are coming from core and major modules so in some cases I'm not going to want to hack up the module to fix a notification, does that mean I just have to live with them?

TIA

Comment: The number of DB connections suggest this *may* have something to do with Watchdog, Drupal's database logger. Try disabling the database logging module and see what happens. PHP's error reporting has absolutely **no** reason to touch a DB otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Fuzzy, its not watchdog, I've turned that off and using syslog. The double on the DB is apache holding things up I gather, its not like there are double the queries, its just load is so high on apache that its holding up the DB

Answer (score 1):

Hm, internally, notices are still triggered, just not shown or logged. Usually this isn't a problem, *however* if you define your own `set_error_handler`, code there might foul things up... Usually, it should do something like `if($errno & error_reporting()){/* only then do something */}`, but if you define your own error handler you might want to check that code (or post it).

Comment: I didn't create my own, just using the default drupal one:set_error_handler('_drupal_error_handler');  which has: if ($errno & (E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_NOTICE)) {

Comment: That is... evil.... Could you replace `(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_NOTICE)` with `error_reporting()` and check performance again?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help. In that drupal sub I just did "return;" and it still didn't help as it seems php just pushes them to syslog anyway. I tried ~E_ALL in php.ini and that didn't help either :(

Comment: PHP will not log them unless told so... Are you a 100% sure you error-reporting level isn't altered somewhere? What _does_ `error_reporting()` return? php.ini is the first to load, but webserver config, .htaccess files, and code itself can all override the level...

Comment: Yeah, there are a bunch. I managed to get it set via doing it in the bootstrap.inc (error_reporting(0)) - So not I'm not getting flooded with messages anymore. Load is still higher then I'd like to see but getting closer. Thanks